# Generating points in space according to a 3D probability grid

Tags: algorithm, random, pseudocode, probability-density

If I have a bunch of point called point_set_A (enclosed by a cube for example), each with a normalized probability value (the values are based on something, e.g. flow velocity).

How do I populate that same space (cube) with (say 100) point_set_B (so come up with x,y,z values), but instead of randomly, I want more points to appear near point_set_A with higher probability values.

Any ideas? Pseudo code or any language will do.

Thanks!

Tim

Comment: http://code-spot.co.za/2009/04/15/generating-random-points-from-arbitrary-distributions-for-2d-and-up/

Comment: Very nice! Haha, this will do for now. Such a simple method... Though this wouldn't work if instead of a probability grid, it's just random probability points...

Comment: You would need to interpolate then. Not a big deal either.